# Writing to a file in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, file, format

I'm trying to write data, formatted in a specific way, to a file in Matlab. The format that I'm trying to achieve is like this:

```
00 : A4AD;
02 : 9889;
03 : 9888;
04 : 9888;
05 : A021;
```

This is the format of a .mif file, if anyone is interested, and I need it in order to load ROM on my DE2 FPGA board.

Currently in Matlab I've got two arrays of size m x n filled with characters and I just need to write those arrays to a file in the format above. Basically I've got two arrays A and B and I want to write the data in these arrays to a file as A : B; where the elements of A are like 00 and the elments of B are like AB03.

I've been able to write a single array by itself using the dlmwrite function, like so:

`dlmwrite('test.hex', Jhex, 'delimiter', '');`

This just gets me each entry from a one array on a single line in the file. I just haven't been able to write both arrays out in the format above. If anyone has any advice on how to go about this I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html)

Comment: @excaza Ok, I've seen fprintf but are is it used similarly as in C? For example should I use  
  
    `fprintf('testfile.hex', '%s : %s;\n',  A, B)`

Comment: Yes, read the documentation...

Comment: @excaza Right, I'm looking through the documentation but I still can't create the format that I need. 

I need to be able to print two matrices of the same size element by element on the same line with a specific format.

 The closest example in the Matlab documentation is them combining two vectors into a matrix and then wrtitting that matrix to a file.

 They don't seem to talk at all about how you can set the format between any two elements of the matrices. Do you have any specific advice on how to do this?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it one line at a time. Either use `for` loop or `arrayfun`:

```
PrintLine = @(a,b) fprintf('testfile.hex', '%s : %s;\n', a, b);
arrayfun(PrintLine,A,B);
```